# Default Adobe reader 9 with internet exp

Tags: internet-explorer, adobe-reader

have 2 PDF apps installed: Adobe Reader 9 and adobe professional 6. For whatever reason, professional 6 is the default PDF plugin for Internet Explorer and not open the file.

How do I make Adobe Reader 9 to be the default PDF plugin (short of uninstalling profesional 6 or reinstalling Adobe Reader)?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to navigate to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations` within a Windows Explorer window to change the file extension association to the program of your choice.

> Open Default Programs by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>   Start button, and then clicking Default Programs.

> Associate a file type with a program
>
> Use this option to fine-tune default programs based on the file type
>   or protocol. For example, you can have all .jpg image files open using
>   a specific program, and .bmp image files open using a different
>   program.

> Set default programs for this computer
>
> Set Program Access and Computer Defaults (available in Windows 7) is a
>   tool to set default programs for activities such as browsing the web
>   and sending e‑mail for everyone who uses the computer. For more
>   information, go to the Windows website and search for "Set Program
>   Access and Computer Defaults."

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7)